# show div on other page angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div with property information in india, if a user clicks on a button,

the page should be redirect on another page and my whole div should be copy

and open on another page

```
<div class="box2">
                    <div style="">
                        <img src="2.jpg" style="border: 2px solid #EEEEEE; height: 180px;" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 select">
                        <div class="borderdiv">
                            <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold">{{i.A}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="borderdiv">
                            <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:lighter">Available For <b>{{i.B}}</b> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="borderdiv">
                            <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">Area <b>{{i.C}}</b> Security <b> Rs. {{i.F}}</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="borderdiv">
                            <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">Rental Unit In<b style="cursor:pointer"> {{i.D}}</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="borderdiv">
                            <span ng-repeat="i in data" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">
                                Features
                                <br />
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eject" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="margin-left:20px;"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="borderdiv">
                            <span ng-repeat="i in data2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">{{i.E}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

this is my div

```
<button ng-click="click()">click to view data</button>
```

this is my button

what i need to do if i want to see the same data on other pages???

Comment: is the second page is in the same project or different project/website?

Comment: same project \...

Comment: you can have same HTML code (DIV) on other page and on the button click you can save the object in $rootScope and read it again from $rootScop on next page.

Comment: can you please show me the code

Comment: add the data2 json content to your post. Also, do you want the same page to be redisplayed or only the data you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a server-side structural template which will generate the `div`. Example in PHP

```
function getViewData() {
    ?>
    <button ng-click="click()">click to view data</button>
    >?php
}
```

And you can add anywhere in your structure if you are using a PHP file like this:

```
<?php getViewData(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go with a **angular factory** which contains the data that you are looking for and use the html template in the respective page.

Button code remains the same as

```
<button ng-click="click()">click to view data</button>
```

Create a new Angular Factory as below

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('appVariables',function(){
        var data2=[];
        return{
                data2,data2
        }
});
```

Your controller should contain the following **click()** method

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('appController',function($scope,appVariables){

        $scope.click=function(){
            appVariables.data2=$scope.data2;
        }
})
```

Go to the another page inject **appVariables** as a dependecy to the controller and you can get the same data2 across your app.

**This code is genric as the information provided by you is very less.**

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a sample for you. I can't create multiple html pages. So you have to put them in different files.

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);]
//JS1
app.controller('page1Controller', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.page1 = {};
  $scope.page1.title  = "Page1";
  
  $scope.click = function(page){
    $rootScope.page = page;
  }
  
}]);


//JS2
app.controller('page2Controller', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.init = function(){
    alert("alrt")
    $scope.page2 = $rootScope.page;
  }
 
  
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="sample">
  
  <!--Page1-->
  <div ng-controller="page1Controller">
    
    <div>{{page1.title}}</div>
   <button ng-click="click(page1)">click to view data</button>
</div>
  
  <!--Page2-->
  <div ng-app="sample">
   <div ng-controller="page2Controller" ng-init="init()">
    
    <div>{{page2.title}}</div>
   
</div>
```